# What is causing this common OpenCV error for me (!_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor')

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling, path

**This was the code I was running:**

```py
import cv2
    
img = cv2.imread("news.jpg")
    
cv2.imshow("Gray", img)
cv2.waitKey(2000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**This was the error that I got:**

```
[ WARN:0@0.144] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('news.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Home\Python\image\Face_detect\face_det.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Gray", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

**I checked my file path and file extension for news.jpg but everything seemed alright even though the file path was giving an error.

Also, this code was working around two weeks back but now for some reason, it has stopped working.**

*If someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks*

Comment: the file **doesn't exist** where the program **looks for it**. it looks for it relative to the **current working directory**, not the directory containing the script. you should have debugged your program before asking. you should have determined that `img` is `None`, and then you should have looked for explanations as to why `imread()` would return `None`, and you would have found advice talking about relative paths and the **current working directory**

Comment: run this: `assert os.path.exists("news.jpg")` (in your script, not anywhere else), which must fail, and then look at `print(os.getcwd())`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go to the next step, please check whether the image exists or not.

This exception message shows up when the `img` is `None` usually.

Or the shape of the image is zero.

### Reproduce

```py
cv2.imshow("", None)
# cv2.imshow("", np.ones((0,0)))
```

```
 (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: I have double checked my file, the image does exist.

Comment: @UtsoChaudhuri could you please print the shape of your image? If it is not `None` try this `print(img.shape)`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry, but as the questioner say `doubled check`, so I think **He couldn't run the print(img.shape)**, so that this way he can go and check why the pictures are `None`

Comment: @toyotaSupra the .imread() command itself doesn't work so the command given by you does not work

Comment: @FavorMylikes when I run the img.shape command I get an attribute error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape')

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have `Windows10`, `11`, `Ubuntu`, all passed.

Comment: @toyotaSupra, I think there is a good direction in the comment on this question by `christoph`. Thx your work, but let's stop here, if you have other questions, make a post.